# Filling in missing ranges in a set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This is a question on filing missing *ranges* of data. Specifically, I have a result set where each row contains a StartDate and EndDate value. Let's say I have:

```
Start     End
1/15      1/20
1/12      3/15
```

I would need a query that produces are adds the following row to the data:

```
1/21      2/11
```

Most other related questions are about filling gaps from a know set (like a list of dates). I this case I'm just looking for the start/end of the missing data.

Comment: in output I think you need 1/21 to 2/11 ... is it right ?

Comment: In your example output, did you mean to write 1/21 instead of 2/21?

Comment: Do you also need to add the year to the date?

Comment: Yes, i put the wrong date in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you meant to write 1/21 instead of 2/21, here's a way to do it:

```
with dates as
(
    select '2016-01-15' as dtStart, '2016-01-20' as dtEnd union all
    select '2016-02-12', '2016-03-15' union all
    select '2016-03-21', '2016-04-11'
),

calcs as
(
    select 
        dateadd(day, 1, dtEnd) as rangeStart,
        (select dateadd(day, -1, min(dtStart)) 
            from dates d2 where d2.dtStart > d.dtEnd) as rangeEnd
    from dates d
)

select *
from calcs c
where c.rangeEnd >= c.rangeStart
```

The table `dates` is just three rows of sample dates.  In the`calcs` table, the `rangeStart` column is the next day after each `dtEnd`.  The `rangeEnd` column takes the next `dtStart` and subtracts a day.  Finally, the last row will have a null because there is now missing range after the last dtEnd, so I ignore the row with the null `rangeEnd` value.

Edit: *If you're unfamiliar with the `with` statement in my code, it's a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx).  I used it here as a quick way to create a table with some sample data in it (dates) and a place to store calculations (calcs).*

Edit2: Since you mentioned using a join in your comment, here's a way to do that:

```
with dates as
(
    select '2016-01-15' as dtStart, '2016-01-20' as dtEnd union all
    select '2016-02-12', '2016-03-15' union all
    select '2016-03-21', '2016-04-11'
),

calcs as
(
    select
        dateadd(day, 1, d1.dtEnd) as rangeStart,
        dateadd(day, -1, min(d2.dtStart)) as rangeEnd
    from dates d1
    join dates d2 on d1.dtEnd < d2.dtStart
    group by d1.dtEnd
)

select *
from calcs
where datediff(day, rangeStart, rangeEnd) >= 0
```

Edit3: updated the datediff inequality to include ranges of one day

Comment: This query assumes there allways is gap, you'll need to edit `c.rangeEnd is not null` to be `c.rangeEnd >= c.rangeStart`

Comment: Thanks, it was more simple than I thought, I had my head stuck on doing it through a join somehow.  I have to do more processing with the missing ranges added back into the source data, so the CTE should work perfect for that.

Comment: @Kratz, I added a solution using a join since you mentioned it.  It uses an unusual join condition with a `<` instead of a `=`.  While this will return multiple rows per match instead of a single row like you might expect, the `group by` and the `min` aggregate function select the right row.  If you have trouble understanding it, run the `calcs` query without the `group by` and the `min`.

Comment: Couldn't the gap be just one day long? I think you're excluding those with the `> 1` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a date table. This will keep your query simple and you can reuse in other queries. Below is a link to an article on creating a date table. Hope this helps.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from 
    (select DISTINCT t1.[end] + 1 'start', t2.start - 1 'end'
            from yourtable t1 
            CROSS JOIN 
            yourtable t2
                WHERE 
                    EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM yourtable t3 WHERE t3.[end] < t2.[start]) 
                AND 
                    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM yourtable t4 WHERE t4.start = t1.[end] + 1)
                AND 
                    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM yourtable t5 WHERE T5.Start BETWEEN t1.[end] + 1 AND  t2.start - 1 OR T5.[end] BETWEEN t1.[end] + 1 AND t2.start - 1)
                AND
                    t1.[end] + 1 <= t2.start - 1
    UNION
        SELECT start,[end] from yourtable) dq
order by start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Table table (Start Date,[End] Date)
Insert into @Table values
('2016-01-15','2016-01-20'),
('2016-02-12','2016-03-15')

;with cteBase as (
    Select *,Gap=DateDiff(DD,Lag([End],1,Start) over (Order By Start),Start) From @Table
)
Select Start=DateAdd(DD,1+Gap*-1,Start),[End]=DateAdd(DD,-1,Start) from cteBase Where Gap<>0
```

Returns

```
Start       End
2016-01-21  2016-02-11
```

Optional for full dataset

```
...
Union All
Select Start,[End] from cteBase
Order by Start
```